# Nuxt hot reload not working when i want change a nuxt page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project. When i want to change a page file hot reload is not complete and for next changes hot reload not working.

[image]

My packages:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "app_panel:dev": "nuxt ./app_panel",
    "app_panel:build": "nuxt ./app_panel build",
    "app_panel:start": "nuxt ./app_panel start",
    "app_panel:generate": "nuxt ./app_panel generate",
    "app_panel:test": "jest --config=app_panel/jest.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1624817847.21691f1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "video.js": "^7.14.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ignore": "4.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a public repo for this? Hard to say where it does come from with just this.

Comment: Hi, do you have more info about this one?